# Python script to curl EPEL repo, AWS S3 and compare version

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am new to python, so wanted to ask if someone has an example how can I achieve below using python.

I have a file in a AWS S3 bucket which contains the version of a EPEL package `0.102.2-4.el7` . Package name `clamav-0.102.2-4.el7.x86_64.rpm`. The file only contains `0.102.2-4.el7` not the whole package name.

EPEL link: `https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/c/`

I want to have a script to read the version in S3 file and compare with above EPEL repo to see if there is a new version available. I also want to check EPEL repo `https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/8/x86_64/Packages/c/`

Ideally this should run as a lambda function and notify SNS topic if new version available.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It's also not entirely clear what you're trying to do.  What would the inputs and desired output be?

Comment: @Chris I tried to explain in above shell script example what I am trying to do. As you can see if there is a NEW_VERSION then it should notify. I can take care of the lambda and SNS part but need to know how to achieve above in python since I am new to python.

Comment: ```
 $ CURRENT_VERSION=0.102.2-3.el7   
 $ curl -s "https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/c/" --list-only |   grep clamd | awk '{print $6}' | awk -F\" '{print $2}' | sed s/clamd-// | sed s/.x86_64.rpm//   0.102.2-4.el7      
 $ NEW_VERSION=$(curl -s   "https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/c/" --list-only | grep clamd | awk '{print $6}' | awk -F\" '{print $2}') | sed s/clamd-// | sed s/.x86_64.rpm//     
 $ [[ CURRENT_VERSION != NEW_VERSION ]] && echo "New version available    ${NEW_VERSION}"    
New version available clamd-0.102.2-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Right, but you didn't.  Please provide inputs (which appear to be a webpage in this case) and desired outputs.  Details here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask